# Trouble on using the readyrails script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to run the following command in the Console (it is related to the [railsready](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) script) in order to update a fresh Linux system on my Virtual Private Server (VPS):

```
root@website:~# wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/joshfng/railsready/raw/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh
```

It should update the system, anyway I get the following output from that script:

```
#################################
########## Rails Ready ##########
#################################

This script must be run as a normal user with sudo privileges
```

Inspecting the script source code I can see:

```
...

#now check if user is root
if [ $script_runner == "root" ] ; then
  echo -e "\nThis script must be run as a normal user with sudo privileges\n"
  exit 1
fi

...
```

The problem, I think, is related to the `root@website:~#`: I should run the above command as a "normal user".

**How can I solve the issue?**

P.S.: I am on a [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the issue by running the command as a normal user, not root. root is the superuser and should only be used when necessary for system administration purposes.

This document may help you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/user-management.html

Comment: Since I am on the Linode VPS and so I am using its console it seems not possible to run code as a "normal user": if I run the 'sudo passwd -l root' command as described in the linked documentation I get the following message: "passwd: password expiry information changed.".

Comment: use "adduser username" to add a normal user. then log out and log back in with the new user, e.g. "ssh username@<server ip>". now run the script with sudo.